# Copying XAML properties in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, is there a way to quickly copy the XAML attributes from one control to another? If a button is a certain color and uses a certain font, is there a way to quickly copy this to another already created button?

Comment: Do you want simply copy, or as the matter of fact, you want property binding?

Comment: you could just create a Style, thats exactly what they were designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using **template, resources and Style**?
And also Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V works.

Comment: will investigate Template, Resources and Style.